# Solving simple integral

Tags: integration, algebra-precalculus

How to solve next integral:
$$\int\frac{x^3+4x^2-5}{x^2}dx$$
I am using power rule for top part wich produce this:
$$\int\frac{\frac{x^2}{2}+4x-5x}{x^2}dx$$
Does my calculation right? How can I continue from here? Please describe all steps and rules used for solving this integral.

Comment: It is obviously wrong. Otherwise $\frac{x^2}{2}=\int x\,dx = \int\frac{x^2}{x}\,dx = \frac{\frac{x^3}{3}}{x}=\frac{x^2}{3}$, according to your logic.

Comment: Which power rule?

Comment: I can not see any rule. $x^3\to \frac12x^2$, $x^2\to x$ and $1\to x$? That can not be right.

Comment: remember to simplify the exponents first!!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you already have is incorrect.
Try this:

$$
\int \frac{x^3+4x^2-5}{x^2}dx = \int  \frac{x^3}{x^2} + \frac{4x^2}{x^2} -\frac{5}{x^2}   dx
$$

$$
=\int (x)  dx + \int 4 dx + \int \frac{5}{x^2} dx
$$

$$
=\frac{x^2}{2} + 4x + \frac{5}{x} + C
$$

Overview of Integration rules:

$$
\int x^n \hspace{2 mm}dx= \frac{x^{n+1}}{n+1} + C
$$

Comment: How $\frac{x^3}{x^2}$ becomes $\frac{x^2}{2}$? and how $-\frac{5}{x^2}$ becomes ${5}{x}$?

Comment: $$ \int x^n = \frac{x^{n+1}}{n+1} + C $$

Check this out as a reference: https://www.mathsisfun.com/calculus/integration-rules.html

Comment: Does this reference apply for $-\frac{5}{x^2}$?

Comment: Yes:
$$
\int \frac{-5}{x^2} dx= -5 \int x^{-2}  dx = -5 \left( \frac{x^{-2+1}}{-2+1} \right)+C = -5 (-x^{-1}) + C = \frac{5}{x} + C
$$

Comment: Can you please add step for $\frac{x^3}{x^2}$?

Comment: $$ \int \frac{x^3}{x^2} dx = \int x^1 \hspace{2 mm} dx = \frac{x^{1+1}}{1+1} + C = \frac{x^2}{2} + C $$

Answer (score 5):

**Hint:**

$$\int \frac{x^3+4x^2-5}{x^2}dx=\int x+4-5x^{-2}dx$$

Comment: Wrong and no steps added. Please read question before answer

Comment: @TeodorKolev Wrong ? What is your reasoning ?

Answer (score 1):

Break down the sum and reduce the polynomial then use the linearity of the integral to get

$$\begin{align}\int\frac{x^3+4x^2-5}{x^2}dx=&\int{\left(x+4-{5\over x^2}\right)}dx\\
=&\int{xdx}+4\int{dx}-5\int\frac{dx}{x^2}\\
=&{x^2\over 2}+4x+{5\over x}+C\end{align}$$

Comment: No steps are added. I do not understand anything

Comment: It should be better now

Answer (score 1):

What you want to use is the linearity of the integral:
\begin{equation} \int \frac{x^3 + 4x^2 -5}{x^2} dx = \int \frac{x^3}{x^2} dx + \int \frac{ 4x^2}{x^2} dx - \int \frac{5}{x^2} dx.\end{equation}Can you continue from here on out?

Comment: No, I can't. Sorry

Comment: Not a problem, we are all here to learn! I think numerous people have answered already so I'll leave it with this. In the future you it would help you to specify how much detail you need, that makes it easier for people to help you.